# Exit matlab script once all figure windows are closed

Tags: matlab

I want to stop the execution of script once all window figures are closed (i.e when I manually finish closing each figure window with a click). I tried doing:

```
x = 1:10;
plot(x,x);
while ~isempty(findall(0,'Type','Figure'))
    if isempty(findall(0,'Type','Figure'))
        exit
    else
        continue
    end
end
```

However with the above code i) no figure is displayed and ii) the loop never ends. So my question is: how can exit matlab execution once all figure windows are closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to update callbacks. For this purpose, use [drawnow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) function inside your `while` loop. If you don't want to exit matlab, do not use `exit`. Your programm script will stop automatically after it will finish `while` loop:

```
x = 1:10;
plot(x,x);
while ~isempty(findall(0,'Type','Figure'))
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will work with multiple figure windows?

Comment: I'd put a `pause(0.01)` in the loop to enable the cpu to process other threads

Answer (score 3):

Instead of polling in a loop, you can use `waitfor`

```
f(1)=figure();
f(2)=figure();
x = 1:10;
plot(x,x);
drawnow;
for ix=1:numel(f)
   waitfor(f(ix));
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will work with multiple figure windows?

Comment: Call `waitfor` for each figure in a loop.

Comment: Can you please update your answer showing this for loop?  Thanks